# Postfix and javax.mail - failed to connect

Tags: java, email

In order to send double-opt-in-mails I need to send eMails to registrees.

So I install Postfix, uncomment the line (`master.cf`):

```
127.0.0.1:submission inet n -   y       -       -       smtpd
```

Then I reload the service using

```
postfix reload
```

And tail-f the `/var/log/mail.log`

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

So far, the output is: `Jul 31 08:50:43 xxx postfix/master[3019]: reload -- version 3.6.4, configuration /etc/postfix`

Ok. Then I compile and execute this java code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "localhost");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(prop);
            MimeMessage registerMail = new MimeMessage(session);
            try {
                    registerMail.setSender(new InternetAddress("xxx@xxx"));
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            registerMail.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, "xxx@xxx");
            registerMail.setSubject("HI");
            registerMail.setContent("adsf", "plain/text");
            Transport.send(registerMail);
    }
```

But I get a exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: failed to connect, no password specified?
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:376)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:222)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:171)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:230)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:100)
    at Snippet.main(Snippet.java:29)
```

The postfix logging does not say a word. So I check the netstat using `netstat -lnp` and this is the output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3019/master
```

From what I can tell: the port is available but java is not able to connect. Why is that? If I need to supply a password, where is the password located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, me stupid. I had to remove this line:

```
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
```